# Best tool to cut 4mm thick straining wire

Tags: tools, wire, metal, metal-cutting

I need to cut several 1.5m hoops of 4mm thick [galvanised steel wire](http://www.farmandgardensupplies.co.uk/Barbed-Razor-And-Straining-Wire/50m-Coil-Of-Straining-Wire-4mm-Diameter.Html).
What's the best tool to do this at a decent pace?

Comment: A heavy side cutter should be able to do the job.

Comment: high tensile of soft?

Answer (score 3):

A common bolt cutter would do well, assuming solid wire and not stranded:

[image]

A more dedicated cable shears would be easier and make cleaner cuts, but it's likely much more expensive:

[image]